# Given two unbounded subsets $X,Y$ of $\mathbb{R},$ do there exist three points of $X$ whose translation and stretch approximates three points of $Y?$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, real-numbers, pigeonhole-principle, diophantine-approximation

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ each are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are bounded below and unbounded above (and therefore infinite).

Given $\varepsilon>0,\ $ do there exist $\ x_1,\ x_2,\ x_3 \in X;\ x_1 < x_2 < x_3;\ \quad y_1,\ y_2,\ y_3 \in Y;\ y_1 < y_2 < y_3,\ $ such that

$$ 1 - \varepsilon < \left\lvert \frac{ \frac{x_2 - x_1}{x_3 - x_1}}{\frac{y_2 - y_1}{y_3 - y_1}} \right\rvert < 1+\varepsilon\quad ?$$

This is equivalent to saying that we can find (many) pairs of triplets $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3),$ such that $\ \frac{x_2 - x_1}{x_3 - x_1}$ and $ \frac{y_2 - y_1}{y_3 - y_1}\ $ are relatively arbitrarily close, which means that each pair of triplets $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3),$ "look similar to each other" albeit for a scaling and translation.

Is $X = \{2^n:\ n\in\mathbb{N} \};\ Y = \{3^n:\ n\in\mathbb{N} \}\ $ a counter-example? I am not sure...

And maybe you construct a back-and-forth counter-example if $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets of arbitrary size, but I'm not sure this construction would extend to $X$ and $Y$ being infinite sets. On the other hand, it seems plausible that there are not good back-and-forth counter-examples if $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets of arbitrary size by some application of the Pigeonhole principle. But I'm not sure about what's true, so it will require more thought.

Also, Stolz-Cesàro theorem might play a role.

Comment: Seems false for 'power'-like sets, e.g. $X = \{10^k : k \in \mathbb N \}$ and $Y=\{2^k: k \in \mathbb N\}$

Comment: @thewatcher that was my first thought also, but I'm not sure/ not yet convinced if that is actually a counter-example.

Comment: I have just edited the question, and I realise the edit makes it look like a completely different question now. However, I think that after the edit it is a more general/broader version of the original question, but other than that it is very similar question in nature to before the edit. I believe that now the question is what I originally intended it to be.

Comment: I don't think thewatcher's example will be a counter-example. Because, for example, $2^{10} \approx 10^3,\ 2^{20} \approx {10}^6\ $ and $\ 2^{40}\approx {10}^{12},\ $ and indeed we have: $$\frac{ 2^{20} - 2^{10} }{ 2^{40} - 2^{10} } = \frac{1}{1049601}  \approx \frac{1}{1001001} = \frac{ {10}^{6} - {10}^3 }{ {10}^{12} - {10}^3 } $$

Comment: I think the answer is no but sets of powers are not sparse enough.  If the numbers in each set grow fast enough the subtraction of $x_1, y_1$ will not matter-they might as well be $0$.  If you take the logs of the inequalities you should be able to use continued fraction approximations to show it will fail but I think sets like $2^{2^n}$ and $3^{3^n}$ will be a counterexample

Comment: @RossMillikan I remain unconvinced. Please prove it.

Comment: @AdamRubinson what Ross said basically works. I think $2^{2^n}$ and $2^{3^n}$ will be an easier counterexample to work with. Specifically, let $X = \{2^{2^n} : n \ge 100\}, Y = \{2^{3^n} : n \ge 100\}$, say. Then $\epsilon = \frac{1}{10}$, say, will be a counterexample (actually, if you increase $100$ sufficiently, then $\epsilon = 0.99$ will be a counterexample). For any $100 \le n_1 < n_2 < n_3$, we have $$\frac{2^{2^{n_2}}-2^{2^{n_1}}}{2^{2^{n_3}}-2^{2^{n_1}}} \approx \frac{2^{2^{n_2}}}{2^{2^{n_3}}},$$ in the sense that their ratio is between $0.9$ and $1.1$, say.

Comment: Similarly, for any $100 \le m_1 < m_2 < m_3$, we have $$\frac{2^{3^{m_2}}-2^{3^{m_1}}}{2^{3^{m_3}}-2^{3^{m_1}}} \approx \frac{2^{3^{m_2}}}{2^{3^{m_3}}}.$$ Therefore, we wish to disprove $$1-\epsilon < \frac{2^{2^{n_3}-2^{n_2}}}{2^{3^{m_3}-3^{m_2}}} < 1+\epsilon.$$ But the ratio is $2^{(2^{n_3}-2^{n_2})-(3^{m_3}-3^{m_2})}$ which is only between $1/2$ and $3/2$ if $2^{n_3}-2^{n_2} = 3^{m_3}-3^{m_2}$, which doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C>1$ be a constant and $(a_n)$ be any sequence s.t. $a_n\ge a_{n-1}+1$ and $a_{n}\ge Ca_{n-1}^2+a_{n-2}$.

Let $i> j> k$ and $r> s> t$ be indices such that $i > r$.

- $x = \dfrac{a_j-a_k}{a_i-a_k}$ is **at most** $\dfrac{a_{i-1}}{a_i-a_{i-2}}$ since $a_j-a_k\le a_j\le a_{i-1}$ and $a_i-a_k\ge a_i-a_{i-2}$.
- $y = \dfrac{a_s-a_t}{a_r-a_t}$ is **at least** $\dfrac{1}{a_{i-1}}$ since $a_s-a_t\ge a_s-a_{s-1}\ge 1$ and $a_r-a_t\le a_r\le a_{i-1}$.

Now notice that $a_i\ge Ca_{i-1}^2+a_{i-2}\implies \dfrac{1}{a_{i-1}}\ge C\dfrac{a_{i-1}}{a_i-a_{i-2}}$, therefore, $y\ge Cx$.

This leads to the conclusion that, for any strictly decreasing triplets of indices $(i, j, k)$ and $(r, s, t)$ with $i\ne r$, one should have
$\dfrac{\dfrac{a_j-a_k}{a_i-a_k}}{\dfrac{a_s-a_t}{a_r-a_t}} > C$ or $\dfrac{\dfrac{a_j-a_k}{a_i-a_k}}{\dfrac{a_s-a_t}{a_r-a_t}} < \dfrac{1}{C}$.

Now just take $X$ and $Y$ to be disjoint subsequences of $(a_n)$! :)

---

For example, $a_n = 3^{3^n}$ is such a sequence for $C = 2$, so you could take $X = \{3^{3^{2n+1}}:n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $Y = \{3^{3^{2n}}:n\in\mathbb N\}$. That is similar to what was been discussed in the comments.

---

**Extra:** I was curious to know if $X = \{2^n: n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $Y = \{3^n: n\in\mathbb N\}$ was a (much simpler) counter-example to your question, so I made [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697516/can-we-always-find-arbitrarily-close-powers-of-a-and-b). As it turns out, it is not.